# Copying whole nodes based on single sub-value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two files, and want to combine/overwrite whole nodes based on a particular matching value in a node tree.

file1.xml

```
  <record>
    <key>key1</key>
    <nodel>
      <field1>source field1</field1>
      <field2>source field2</field2>
      <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
    </nodel>
  </record>
```

file2.xml

```
  <record>
    <key>key2</key>
    <nodel>
      <field1>match field1</field1>
      <field2>match field2</field2>
      <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
    </nodel>
  </record>
```

Desired output:

```
  <record>
    <key>key1</key>
    <nodel>
      <field1>source field1</field1>
      <field2>source field2</field2>
      <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
    </nodel>

    <nodel>
      <field1>match field1</field1>
      <field2>match field2</field2>
      <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
    </nodel>
  </record>
```

So, I want to check for a match in the searchkey, between the two files, and, if it matches, copy the whole node of the match to the output file, but keep the original key, not the match one. I will then want to delete the original nodel, though am happy to do that as a later transform.

I did ask a recent similar question for matching on the `<key>` nodes, but couldn't figure out how to modify it to achieve this desired result.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume in reality your file1.xml and file2.xml will contain more than one record each? And some node structure above the records? What do you want to do with that?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete but short solution. :)

Comment: @TToni: yes, there are a couple of hundred records in each file, but I shortened it for brevity. The only node above in this instance is the root, though I'd be interested in a generic implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kNodeBySearchkey" match="*[searchkey]" use="searchkey"/>
    <xsl:param name="pSource2" select="'file2.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSource2" select="document($pSource2,/)"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[searchkey]">
        <xsl:variable name="vKey" select="searchkey"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$vSource2">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('kNodeBySearchkey',$vKey)">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<record>
    <key>key1</key>
    <nodel>
        <field1>source field1</field1>
        <field2>source field2</field2>
        <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
    </nodel>
    <nodel>
        <field1>source field1</field1>
        <field2>source field2</field2>
        <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
    </nodel>
</record>
```

**Note**: I you don't want to preserve the original `nodel`, just strip away the first `xsl:call-template` instruction.

Comment: That's ideal, Alejandro, and thanks for identifying where the first node is copied. Would you mind explaining what the `*[searchkey]` term means. I've seen examples of simple matches, but don't understand this syntax. (I couldn't find out what the `*[not(self::type)]` syntax meant in the other example either.)

Comment: @debs: `*[searchkey]` pattern means *any element having at least one `searchkey` element child*.  `*[not(self::type)]` means *any element except `type` element*.

Comment: @Alejandro: thanks so much for that. These sort of patterns aren't easily searchable, so I hadn't managed to find out what they meant. Your help and advice is very much appreciated. I'm marking this as the answer as I found it slightly easier to follow, but they are both welcomed, and should help in furthering my understanding.

Comment: @debs: I'm glad it was helpful. Ask any time.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:file2>
  <record>
    <key>key2</key>
    <nodel>
      <field1>match field1</field1>
      <field2>match field2</field2>
      <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
    </nodel>
  </record>
 </my:file2>

 <xsl:variable name="vFile2"
      select="document('')/*/my:file2/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[starts-with(name(),'node')]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select=
   "$vFile2/*[starts-with(name(),'node')]
                  [searchkey=current()/searchkey]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()" mode="copy">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided first XML document**:

```
<record>
    <key>key1</key>
    <nodel>
        <field1>source field1</field1>
        <field2>source field2</field2>
        <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
    </nodel>
</record>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<record>
   <key>key1</key>
   <nodel>
      <field1>source field1</field1>
      <field2>source field2</field2>
      <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
   </nodel>
   <nodel>
      <field1>match field1</field1>
      <field2>match field2</field2>
      <searchkey>myname</searchkey>
   </nodel>
</record>
```

**Note**: The second XML document is represented inline in the stylesheet -- this is only for convenience. In practice, it will reside in its own file and only the definition of `$vFile2` will be changed to:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vFile2"
      select="document('someFileURIHere')/*"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. I tried that, and your code worked well, though I got an unwanted `<nodel xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="my:my">` in the second node.  Also, I tried it with the vFile2, but got a stack overflow, and the output was just the second node repeated. I'll try and post my code in case I made an error.

Comment: @debs: Yes, the code works and I am always verifying this before publishing a solution. The unwanted namespace will not be there when the second XML document is in its own file. As for your stack overflow, I cannot guess without seeing the code you used.

Comment: @debs: I have added a small correction to my solution -- now it does work with the second XML document in a file.

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, I've spotted the mode="copy" addition, and will try to figure out what it's doing!

Comment: @debs: The mode is what prevents infinite recursion. Thus the `node1` from file1 and `node1` from file2 are not processed by the same template.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt at the filename input:

xsl

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="pSource2" select="'file2.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vFile2" select="document($pSource2)/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[starts-with(name(),'node')]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "$vFile2/*[starts-with(name(),'node')]
                  [searchkey=current()/searchkey]
   "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives

```
<record>
<key>key1</key>
<nodel>
<field1>source field1</field1>
<field2>source field2</field2>
<searchkey>myname</searchkey>
</nodel>
<nodel>
<field1>match field1</field1>
<field2>match field2</field2>
<searchkey>myname</searchkey>
</nodel>
```

With the second node repeated until it gives up.

Comment: I have added a small correction to my solution -- now it does work with the second XML document in a file. Please, do not specify new information as an answer -- just edit your question.